# Windows Phone - get zoom level from distance

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dictionary, geocoding

I am not good at math so please help me with this. I have distance in meters and I need to calculate zoom level and center to map from this. How can I do that? I started with this but now I am completly lost:

```
var sCoord = new GeoCoordinate(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y);
var eCoord = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);
var distance = sCoord.GetDistanceTo(eCoord);
```

Thanks

Comment: Simply map distance intervals to zoom levels

Answer (score 0):

If I understated you correctly, you can achieve the goal by using the following code

```
var start = ...;
var finish = ...;

// Calculate center
var center = new GeoCoordinate((start.Latitude + finish.Latitude) / 2,
     (start.Longitude + finish.Longitude) / 2);
var width = Math.Abs(start.Longitude - finish.Longitude);
var height = Math.Abs(start.Latitude - finish.Latitude);

Map.SetView(new LocationRectangle(center, width, height));
```