# How to adjust zoom level on windows phone 8.1 map by pushpins

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, maps

I am working with map control in windows phone 8.1(RT) application ,
I have two Custom Push Pins on my map , one in source address and second is Destination address , I want to change zoom level according to both push pins 
, means both pins are display on screen with path 
my current zoom level is

```
 mapLocation.ZoomLevel = 14;
```

I want to change zoom level according to both Location

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085382/windows-phone-get-zoom-level-from-distance

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the boundaries of multiple pushpins(positions)in WinRt using `GeoboundingBox.TryCompute` and then set map's view to these boundaries.

```
        try
        {
        Geopoint sourcePoint = --Source point here--;
        Geopoint destPoint= --Dest point here--;

                //Calculate Boundries
                var locations = new List<BasicGeoposition>();
                locations.Add(sourcePoint.Position);
                locations.Add(destPoint.Position);
                var boundries = GeoboundingBox.TryCompute(locations);
                await SMapControl.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(boundries, new Thickness(100), MapAnimationKind.None);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }
```

Note the second parameter to `TrySetViewBoundsAsync` method is the margin added around the calculated boundaries.